# Why Custom fields description is not working WordPress Version 5.4.2?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

Here is my code which I tried to get description but I am not getting proper response. As I search, someone gave me suggestion to make following function in function.php but it still not working.

```
remove_filter('acf_the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

**Here is my code**

```
<?php echo get_field( "category_description", 'category_'.$cat_id ); ?>
```

Kindly hint me where is the issue? How I get proper response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did it work in earlier versions - are you saying this has stopped working in 5.4.2? My ACF is rusty but I guess that's looking up a value from wp_termmeta - is there actually a category_description there?

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump()` of `$cat_id` to make sure you're passing the value you need? And/or using `the_field()` instead of `echo get_field()`?

Comment: Yes, it was working but when upgrade version and stop suddenly. Also I tested properly, $cat_id given response of id. I checked with the_field() but still not getting response.